# Why is Facebook getting page feeds twice?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I'm looking for the feeds of a page with `Graph API`. This is standard endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/379715302125701/posts?access_token=mytoken
```

but it returns every post twice. Why? Temporary error or what? Other service I got haven't any problems.

Comment: There's a bug report in Facebook's platform bug tracker about this at the moment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/706819176094748

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your API request with my access_token and GraphAPI return just one item for every post.
I tried it on another Page and get correct data too.

Maybe try with other app/access_token.

Comment: The problem is only with this application. Can be that admin of the app manage many pages? I don't have any other idea :O

Comment: It is normal situation that 1 admin have many funpages to manage. In my opinion it is not cause of problems. In request you do not pass information about admin.